# Как выставить пределы от 170 и до 180 на pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня есть домашнее задания , нужно провести сравнения двух выборок , а именно там есть столбец - рост и весь , около 15 тыс значений , мне надо взять выборку 20 человек по росту от 170 до 180 и сравнить вес людей в общем файле с выборкой 20 случайных людей которые отбирались по росту и сравнить их веса и посчитать средний вес в общем фале и  в выборки и решить они статистически значимы или нет. 
Не могу сделать именно сортировку по весу

Пробовал через     print(data[data.height_sm >= 170 ][data.height_sm <180 ].head(20))
 Выдаёт сортировку но я не понимаю как дальше эту часть кода вставить в выборку  данных

```
data = pd.read_csv('hw_25000.csv', names = ['index', 'height_inches', 'weight_pounds'],header  = 0 )
data.head(20)
print(data[data.height_sm >= 170 ][data.height_sm <180 ].head(20))
sort = data[data.height_sm >= 170 ],[data.height_sm <180 ]
data['sort'].head(20)
#Выдает ошибку ValueError: Length of values does not match length of 
 index
```

В Идеале должен появиться ещё отфильтрованные 20 человек по росту от 170 до 180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[data.height_sm >= 170][data.height_sm < 180]` - это называется [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy), так делать не рекомендуется т.к. это может вызывать проблемы.

Более правильный и безопасный вариант:

```
data.loc[(data["height_sm"] >= 170) & (data["height_sm"] < 180)]
```

или SQL-подобный:

```
data.query("170 <= height_sm < 180")
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще чем я думал и сам и ответил в тексте где прошу помощи ))

Я начал делать новую выборку

```html
new_v = data[data.height_sm >= 170 ][data.height_sm <180 ]
```

дальше просто написал

```
new_v.head(20)
```

и получил выборку по пределам от 170 до 180

```
index   height_inches   weight_pounds   height_sm   weight_kg   sample
2   3   69.39874    153.0269    176.272800  68.862105   3.0
3   4   68.21660    142.3354    173.270164  64.050930   4.0
4   5   67.78781    144.2971    172.181037  64.933695   5.0
5   6   68.69784    123.3024    174.492514  55.486080   6.0
6   7   69.80204    141.4947    177.297182  63.672615   7.0
7   8   70.01472    136.4623    177.837389  61.408035   8.0
8   9   67.90265    112.3723    172.472731  50.567535   9.0
11  12  67.62333    114.1430    171.763258  51.364350   12.0
12  13  68.30248    125.6107    173.488299  56.524815   13.0
13  14  67.11656    122.4618    170.476062  55.107810   14.0
14  15  68.27967    116.0866    173.430362  52.238970   15.0
17  18  68.64927    142.9733    174.369146  64.337985   18.0
19  20  67.13118    124.0449    170.513197  55.820205   20.0
20  21  67.83379    141.2807    172.297827  63.576315   21.0
21  22  68.87881    143.5392    174.952177  64.592640   22.0
23  24  68.42187    129.5027    173.791550  58.276215   24.0
24  25  67.62804    141.8501    171.775222  63.832545   25.0
25  26  67.20864    129.7244    170.709946  58.375980   26.0
26  27  70.84235    142.4235    179.939569  64.090575   27.0
27  28  67.49434    131.5502    171.435624  59.197590   28.0
```